# Making PyCharm 'look' like Sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, pycharm

I imported the same color scheme I use in sublime text, but the syntax coloring in sublime does a better job of coloring methods, classes, data types, etc. is it possible to make PyCharm look the same as sublime text 2?

PyCharm

[image: pyCharm]

Sublime Text 2

[image]

Answer (score 16):

After doing some mix-ups, I found an exact working theme.
Hint: click on images to preview in high resolution.

> **Follow these steps**

1. Install "Monocai Color Theme" from settings>plugins

[image]

2. Select Darcula theme in "Appearance and Behavior"

[image]

3. Select Monokai color scheme under "Editor>Color Scheme"

[image]

4. Final look

[image]

Answer (score 14):

What you want is a good replacement theme such as [these here](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes).

/edit:
If you still want to further modify the colours for your syntax you need to go to **Preferences -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts**.

[image]

Once there you can select the language you want and customise the colour and look for different parts of the syntax. You can also save that colour scheme for future use. Further information [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html).

Comment: I installed those, the problem is that it does not color the class and methods as seen above

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I have updated my answer with more info.

Comment: Link to replacement themes is broken.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes) you can find an updated link [Editor's note (2021): the website is dead, so updated doesn't describe it anymore] to ***sublime text*** code [color themes](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes).

If you also want to add a **code map bar** like the one on ***sublime***, take a look at the PyCharm plugin [CodeGlance](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/7275-codeglance).